# Find every pixels RGB value from multiple frames

Tags: python, rgb, pixel

I have two videos. One at 10 fps and other one is the same video and 10 fps but it is interpolated from the same videos 5 fps version. I want to see how accurate the frame interpolation by comparing the RGB values of every frame. I can extract every frame from both videos. However, I can only get the RGB values of only 1 frame. I use the following code:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('frame1.jpg') 
pix = im.load()
for x in range(0,640):
    for y in range(0,480):
        print pix[x,y]
```

This code can only found the RGB values in 1 frame and I have hundreds of frames. The frames of my original video are named frame1.jpg frame2.jpg ... frame 100.jpg etc. and other videos frames are saved as frames1.jpg frames2.jpg ... frames100.jpg etc. Is there a way to automate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glob` (comes natively with Python) to load all the images and store them simultaneously, or process them one at a time.

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

for frames in glob.glob({path}+"*.jpg"):
    im = Image.open(frames)
    pix=im.load()
    for x in range(0,640):
        for y in range(0,480):
            print pix[x,y]
```

This will do what you did, but it will loop over all files in path with JPG format. If you want something more specific, you can add requests and I'll add to my answer. But this will sequentially load all images, allowing you to process them subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

Put all that stuff in a loop.

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    file = 'frame%d.jpg'%i
    im = Image.open(file)
    # ...
```